# how do i select multiple records for jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

i know how to delete records for jqgrid, but i realise i cannot select at any one time more than 1 row for deletion.

is it even possible to select multiple rows for deletion?

EDIT:
found the answer

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

multiselect: true

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Aoptions

multiselect: true

So it would like this..

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({

            height: 500,
            width: 1000,

          url:'admin/summary_server.php?t=p',
          datatype: "json",
          colNames:['ID', 'Project', 'Action'],
          colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id_project', width:50},
            {name:'title',index:'title', width:250},
            {name:'action',index:'id_project', width:250,  formatter:project_actionLink}
          ],
          rowNum:10,
          rowList:[10,20,30],
          editurl: 'admin/summary_server.php?t=p',
          pager: jQuery('#pager2'),
          sortname: 'id_project',
          viewrecords: true,

          ***multiselect: true,
          multiboxonly: true,***

          sortorder: "desc",
          caption:"JSON Example"
      }).navGrid('#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:true});
```